# converting RGB numpy array to HSV

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I couldn't find function to convert RGB numpy array into HSV. I tried the matplotlib.colors.rgb_to_hsv() , but it hasn't have any changes.

Does someone know how to solve it?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors as clr

#run rgb analysis for specified coordinate
img1 = mpimg.imread("/home/pi/Desktop/plateanalysis/0512/croppedimg4.png")

c = 120  #spacing
for i in range(0,5):
    for j in range(0,5):
        slice = img1[70+i*c:70+i*c+30, 95+j*c:95+j*c+30]
        ij = np.mean(slice, axis = 0)
        ij = np.mean(ij, axis = 0)
        clr.rgb_to_hsv(ij)
        np.set_printoptions(precision = 2)
        print(i+1, j+1, "=", ij*255, "\t", sep = "")
```

Comment: Go to the following Link .
[converting rgb to hsv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15278323/converting-image-from-rgb-to-hsv-color-space)

Comment: Check this out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612361/convert-rgb-values-to-equivalent-hsv-values-using-python